# Mean of random variable X

Tags: definite-integrals, random-variables, expected-value, constraints

$X$ - random variable, $P(X<1)=0$ and $P(X>e)=0$, $y \in [1,e]$ and $P(X<y) = \int\limits_1^y \frac{1}{x} \ dx$.

Is it correct to find $E[X]$ in the following way?

$ F_X(y) = \int\limits_1^y \frac{1}{x} dx = \ln(y) $

$ f_X(y) = \frac{1}{y} $

$ E[X] = \int\limits_1^e f_X(y)y  \  dy = \int_1^e dy = e - 1$

Comment: Minus being lazy about carrying domain restrictions along through the calculation, yes, that's fine. (And that laziness is pretty standard, you just need to be aware of it to avoid making silly mistakes).

Comment: I have the same result.